# Length of a water column executing SHM in a U-shaped Tube

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, harmonics

I was watching the lecture 30 of [Walter Lewin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLERGeJGfknBR3pXCPlV3bgb_qHCSNOdBf) ( 8.01 ). Here is a link:

https://youtu.be/hAYeA3Wwb4U

At 29:30, when he was describing the [SHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) of water in a U shaped tube. Lewin says that for the length of a water column, we have actually two lengths ( as the Tube has a curve at bottom ). So, we take the average of two lengths. So far its ok.

But, then he says that in reality, the length should be taken a little bit more than the average value of $L1+L2/2$. Then, he asks why it should be so?

I have tried my best to figure it out, but unable to do so. So can you please explain why it would be so?

Edit:
I found his comment where he is answering the question himself, but by doing the integration of dm as function of R. I get L even smaller than average one but it should be larger! Can anyone knows what he is trying to say?

Here is his comment:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take for the lower part of the U the inner part being a half circle with $r$ . The outer part of a half circle with $r+2 \ cm$, then the calculated length wold be:

$$L=(\pi(r+2)+\pi r)/2=\pi(r+1)$$

But, the volume will not be $A \times L$ , if you really calculate it.

You could not make it a straight tube Length $L$ with radius $1 \ cm$.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't get right. The question still remains and L is not a straight line. In lecture, Walter Lewin takes L as the average of two arc lengths. He never assumes assume L to be straight. He just assume that by taking the average we would be close to effective L ( arc length ).

Comment: When he calculates the  volume to get the mass, he uses L as the length of a straight tube with area A. What he says is that it  is not exactly true that you can determine the length in this way if you use V=L*A. so you should try tu calculate the volume of the lower part of the tube, and see that it corresponds to a longer L if you  do V=L*A

Comment: Oh, now I get to some extent. Thanks for your kind help.